# Script is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: linux

First off I found this guide, which details exactly what I need.

https://imagemagick.org/script/connected-components.php

[image]

For the life of me I cannot get this to work. Anyone have any idea?

I've tried a bunch of variations of the scripts listed in the guide.

Also when I run convert /var/www/mailtovoice/audrey/sean_look_grey.png -define connected-components:verbose=true -connected-components 8 /var/www/mailtovoice/audrey/sean_look4.png

I get 1000s of objects. When I converted it to an image with just 3 objects I get 100s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark has the right idea, but the solution is much simpler than he posted, since ImageMagick -connected-components can do the filtering and output directly.

input:
[image]

Unix line endings (for windows use `^` rather than `\` )

```
convert image.png \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=100 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 4 \
result.png
```

[image]

Comment: When I use this, it gets converted to a solid black image? I tried a lot variations of this same code with the same output.

Comment: What is your version of ImageMagick and its date and what is your platform? `convert -version` for IM 6 or `magick -version for IM 7. Your imagemagick could be older than connected-components. Did you start with the same PNG image that you posted?

Comment: Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2018-09-28, on Ubuntu 16.04.2 And yes I started with the image I posted.

Comment: That should be fine unless you got a bad patch. What was your exact command line and image? Be sure if you used my command, that you remove and spaces after the `\\`. Or remove all the \ and make the command one long single line.

Comment: convert /var/www/mailtovoice/audrey/sean_raw.png \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=100 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 4 \
/var/www/mailtovoice/audrey/sean_duh_fuck.png                                                                               [link](https://imgur.com/a/R8TLmVN) to original image                                                         [link](https://imgur.com/a/GiQAa1i) output image. Dude thank you so much for trying to help. This has been driving me nuts. Also there were not spaces at the end.

Comment: Yea I tried uninstalling and reinstalling imagemagick and still having the same output. a black image.

Comment: Try this: `convert image.png -define connected-components:area-threshold=100 -define connected-components:mean-color=true -connected-components 4 result.png`. If that does not work, then something is wrong with your IM version - perhaps a bad patch from your Linux Distro or they skipped improvements and only patched for security. This command works fine for me on IM 6.9.10.13 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra with the image downloaded from your link. If you set the area-threshold to 0 or remove that define, does it still remove everything?

Comment: Try the exact example at https://imagemagick.org/script/connected-components.php. Does that work?

Comment: Connected Components was only introduced in IM 6.8.9.10. By version, you are one version short. But your patch date is 9/28/2018. If your Linux distro actually patched for enhancements, it should work for you. But if they only patched for security fixes, then you could be out of luck.

Comment: Note that the mean-color=true define came even later. Try `convert image.png -define connected-components:area-threshold=100 -define connected-components:mean-color=true -connected-components 4 -auto-level result.png. If that shows regions, then the connected-components initial part is working and you are getting the id numbers output, which will all be small in a Q16 number scheme and would be too dark to see without the -auto-level. If that is the case, then the define for mean-color=true has not been included in your distro.

Comment: Excellent - that is much simpler than my answer! I was not aware IM could generate the filtered image for you - so you live and learn, thank you!

Comment: I got it working on my windows machine. I have no idea why linux one wont work. I've tried it across different versions, and still no luck.

Comment: As I mentioned, your Linux version is one version too old, even though the patch date is current, and probably did not include the patches for any or all -connected-components features. This is an issue in my opinion with patching in Linux rather than actually updating the ImageMagick version completely.

Answer (score 1):

The method suggested by Fred (@fmw42) is far simpler and preferable to that shown in this answer, so all but die-hard enthusiasts should use Fred's answer. Rather than delete mine, I will leave it showing as it could form the basis for other more demanding/involved processing.

---

This is a rather funny way to do it... find all the blobs. i.e. connected components:

```
convert spotty.png -define connected-components:verbose=true  -connected-components 4 null:
```

which gives you something like this but with 2,000+ lines:

```
Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
0: 860x482+0+0 431.5,239.7 405738 gray(0)
800: 43x263+252+219 265.9,350.5 2458 gray(255)
2: 21x226+276+0 288.9,111.2 1540 gray(255) 
2216: 5x16+107+445 109.3,452.9 65 gray(255)
910: 7x15+276+228 279.0,234.5 63 gray(255)
491: 7x14+651+150 654.1,156.6 54 gray(255)
1207: 7x9+735+282 737.9,285.8 53 gray(255)
2313: 6x9+147+457 149.6,460.9 48 gray(255)
985: 8x9+754+238 757.3,242.0 48 gray(255)
...
...
```

Now look for all the ones with a size (second-to-last field) less than 1000 using `awk` and print the region:

```
convert spotty.png \
   -define connected-components:verbose=true \
   -connected-components 4 null:             | 
   awk -v thresh=1000 'NR>1 && $(NF-1)<thresh{print " -region " $2 " -colorize 100%"}'
```

**Output**

```
-region 5x16+107+445 -colorize 100%
-region 7x15+276+228 -colorize 100%
-region 7x14+651+150 -colorize 100%
-region 7x9+735+282 -colorize 100%
...
...
```

Now reload the original image, set the fill colour for colorised regions to red and regenerate the list of regions to be filled exactly as above:

```
convert spotty.png -fill red $(convert spotty.png -define connected-components:verbose=true  -connected-components 4 null: | awk -v thresh=1000 'NR>1 && $(NF-1)<thresh{print " -region " $2 " -colorize 100%"}' ) result.png
```

[image]

---

The command generated boils down to:

```
convert spotty.png -threshold 50% -fill red \
   -region 56x16+107+445 -colorize 100%     \
   -region 70x15+276+228 -colorize 100%     \
   -region ...           -colorize 100%     \
   ...
   ...
   result.png
```

Comment: When I implement your code I get a solid red image, lol. When I implement the code from the comment below, I get a solid black image. Something weird is going on for sure.